# not able to use javascript inside the razer

Tags: javascript, razor

I have following view side code in cshtml

```
<div class="item-grid">

                @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
                {
                    var itemboxid = "item-box_" + @product.Id;

                      <div class="item-box" style="display:none;"  id="@itemboxid">

                         @Html.Partial("_ProductBox_Category", product)

                      </div>

                }

            </div>
```

by defalt the content is hidden.i am trying to unhide the content using following javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search-box-button").click(function () {

            var city = $('#city').val();

            var serchterm = $('#small-searchterms1').val();

            @foreach(var product in Model.Products)
            {


                @:if(city==@product.city)
                {

                var pro_id = "#item-box_" + product.Id;

                @:$("@pro_id").show();



                }


             }

        });
});
```

`#city` is the id value of the textbox where we can enter the text data
but this code is not working fine please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why do you want to write razor code inside JavaScript? Why cant you write JavaScript code itself? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: at first i tried javascript code itself.but i failed to achive what i needed.

Comment: These syntax will never work if you strip out JavaScript code from view to separate js file (which ideally you should be doing it). If you could explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, probably someone can help with js code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `<text>` tags (and have fixed your prod id at the end - it looks you were getting your js and razor variables mixed up):

```razor
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#search-box-button").click(function() {

     var city = $('#city').val();
     var serchterm = $('#small-searchterms1').val();

         @foreach(var product in Model.Products) {

          <text>
               if (city == '@product.city') {
                 var pro_id = "#item-box_@product.Id";

                 $(pro_id).show();
               }
          </text>

         }

   });
 });
```